# How do I re-approach creating modals for multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am working on a side project that involves multiple modals on one page. I followed the W3 schools modal tutorial, but it doesn't perform exactly how I want. Note: I am extremely new with JS.

How do I serve up a similar but different image with a different SRC (https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History.jpg) after clicking on the modal, rather than showing the same image zoomed in?

Here is a link to my codepen project: https://codepen.io/jkramer25/project/editor/AooxzJ

Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " js";</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>Horizontal Timeline</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="cd-h-timeline js-cd-h-timeline margin-bottom-md">

    <div class="cd-h-timeline__container container">
      <div class="cd-h-timeline__dates">
        <div class="cd-h-timeline__line">
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/01/1839" class="cd-h-timeline__date cd-h-timeline__date--selected">1839</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1841" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1841</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1902" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1902</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1904" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1904</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1912" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1912</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/1918" class="cd-h-timeline__date">1918</a></li>
          </ol>

          <span class="cd-h-timeline__filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__line -->
      </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__dates -->
        
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#0" class="text-replace cd-h-timeline__navigation cd-h-timeline__navigation--prev cd-h-timeline__navigation--inactive">Prev</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0" class="text-replace cd-h-timeline__navigation cd-h-timeline__navigation--next">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__container -->
 
    <div class="timeline-indicators-flex container"><!--Previous, Next, Swipe tip-->
      <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-left">
        <p>Previous</p>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-center">
        <p id="swipe-tip">Swipe or Use Arrows to Navigate</p>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-indication color-contrast-medium align-right">
        <p>Next</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cd-h-timeline__events">
      <ol>
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 1-1839----------------------- -->
        <li class="cd-h-timeline__event cd-h-timeline__event--selected text-component">
          <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container"> 
<!--
            <div class="jumplinks-timeline">
              <a href="#hammacher-history">
                <div class="jumplinks-timeline-button">Hammacher History</div>
              </a>
              <a href="#us-history">
                <div class="jumplinks-timeline-button">US History</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          -->          
            <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <div>
                <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1839</h2>
                <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
              </div>
              <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
                <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
                 
                <img class="myImg" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History-100x100_1.jpg" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100px;">
              
              </div>
            </div>
              <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium"> 
                Albert Hammacher, the man who would eventually provide half of our company's name, is born on February 16, 1839 in Leichlingen, a town in the North Rhine-Westphalia region of Germany. Hammacher would come to be viewed as one of the leading figures in the hardware industry in the U.S. and Germany during the late 19th and early 20th centuries.
              </p>    

<hr class="timeline-divider">

            <div id="us-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
              <img class="myImg"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_US_History-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              United States Army officer George Armstrong Custer is born in Ohio. Custer developed a strong reputation leading Union
              troops during the Civil War-despite graduating last in his class at West Point-and attained the rank of brigadier
              general at age 23. After the Civil War, he was dispatched to the west to fight in the Indian Wars. Custer and all the
              men with him (two of his brothers among them) were killed at the Battle of the Little Bighorn in 1876, in a battle that
              has come to be known as "Custer's Last Stand."
            </p> 
          </div>                      
        </li>
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 2-1841----------------------- -->
        <li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
          <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">
            <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <div>
                <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1841</h2>
                <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
              </div>
              <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
                <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
              <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_HS_History-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              William Schlemmer, whose name will come to be associated with a landmark New York City store and America's
              longest-running catalog, is born on April 20, 1841 in the Westphalia region of Germany.
            </p>

<hr class="timeline-divider">

            <div id="us-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
              <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1841_US_History-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              William Henry Harrison served the shortest tenure of any U.S. president, just 32 days, and became the first to die in
              office. Vice President John Tyler is sworn in as the nation's 10th president on April 4, 1841.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>       
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 3-1902----------------------- -->
        <li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
          <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">
            <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
              <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                <div>
                  <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1902</h2>
                  <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
                  <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
                <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                  src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1902_HS_History-100x100.jpg">
              </div>
              </div>
          
              <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
                Despite the fact that there are fewer than 600 automobiles in New York City and no gas stations, Hammacher Schlemmer
                introduces the first Auto Parts Department, selling parts and tools for the "horseless carriage" including a Motorist
                Touring Kit, which allows drivers to fix a flat or blown gasket.As the automobile gains in popularity and begins to come
                into more widespread use, Hammacher Schlemmer purchases their own automobile which they used to begin the first
                home-delivery parcel service for customers-a novel idea in its day.
              </p>
        
<hr class="timeline-divider">
        
            <div id="us-history"></div>
              <div class=timeline-image-flex>
                <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
                <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                  src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1902_US_History-100x100.jpg">
              </div>
              <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
                Theodore Roosevelt becomes the first American President to ride in an automobile when he rides in a Columbia Electric
                Victoria through Hartford, Connecticut.
              </p>
            
        

<hr class="timeline-divider">

          <div id="us-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Extraordinary Items</em>
              <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1902_Extraordinary-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              Weighing up to 750 lbs., the "Star" Screw-cutting Engine Lathe was operated via foot pedals. Chief among its many
              virtues was its outstanding construction, described as "Heavy, rigid, accurate, correct in design and finish, combining
              throughout the best material, with the highest class of workmanship."
            </p>

<hr class="timeline-divider">

          <div id="us-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Media</em>
              <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1902_Media-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              To help motorists reduce their repair bills, Hammacher Schlemmer offers the tourist autokit, "the highest type of
              repairing outfit procurable". The kit contains 38 tools for both permanent and emergency use, "conveniently packed in a
              strong, leather-edged canvas roll."

            </p>     

<hr class="timeline-divider">

          <div id="us-history"></div>
            <div class=timeline-image-flex>
              <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Catalogs</em>
              <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
                src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1902_Catalog-100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
              Hammacher Schlemmer publishes catalog No. 115, a 300-page edition featuring tools for machinists and metal workers. The
              opening page serves notice of the company's tradition for quality and innovation: "Since 1848 we have been selling tools
              to the trade. We have always aimed to sell strictly high-grade goods, and to keep in advance of all improvements
              introduced which bore evidence of real practical value."
            </p>
        </div>
        </li>
        
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 4-1904----------------------- -->
<li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
  <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">
    <div id="#hammacher-history"></div>
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <div>
        <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1904</h2>
        <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
        <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1904_HS_History-100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Despite the fact that there are fewer than 600 automobiles in New York City and no gas stations, Hammacher
      Schlemmer
      introduces the first Auto Parts Department, selling parts and tools for the "horseless carriage" including a
      Motorist
      Touring Kit, which allows drivers to fix a flat or blown gasket.As the automobile gains in popularity and begins
      to come
      into more widespread use, Hammacher Schlemmer purchases their own automobile which they used to begin the first
      home-delivery parcel service for customers-a novel idea in its day.
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    <div id="us-history"></div>
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1904_US_History-100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Theodore Roosevelt becomes the first American President to ride in an automobile when he rides in a Columbia
      Electric
      Victoria through Hartford, Connecticut.
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    <div id="us-history"></div>
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Media</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1904_Media_100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      To help motorists reduce their repair bills, Hammacher Schlemmer offers the tourist autokit, "the highest type of
      repairing outfit procurable". The kit contains 38 tools for both permanent and emergency use, "conveniently packed
      in a
      strong, leather-edged canvas roll."

    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    <div id="us-history"></div>
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Catalogs</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1904_Catalog_100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Hammacher Schlemmer publishes catalog No. 115, a 300-page edition featuring tools for machinists and metal
      workers. The
      opening page serves notice of the company's tradition for quality and innovation: "Since 1848 we have been selling
      tools
      to the trade. We have always aimed to sell strictly high-grade goods, and to keep in advance of all improvements
      introduced which bore evidence of real practical value."
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 5-1912----------------------- -->
<li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
  <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">
    
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <div>
        <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1912</h2>
        <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
        <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1912_HS_History100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Despite the fact that there are fewer than 600 automobiles in New York City and no gas stations, Hammacher
      Schlemmer
      introduces the first Auto Parts Department, selling parts and tools for the "horseless carriage" including a
      Motorist
      Touring Kit, which allows drivers to fix a flat or blown gasket.As the automobile gains in popularity and begins
      to come
      into more widespread use, Hammacher Schlemmer purchases their own automobile which they used to begin the first
      home-delivery parcel service for customers-a novel idea in its day.
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1912_US_History-100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Theodore Roosevelt becomes the first American President to ride in an automobile when he rides in a Columbia
      Electric
      Victoria through Hartford, Connecticut.
    </p>



    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    
    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Extraordinary Items</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1912_Extraordinary100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Weighing up to 750 lbs., the "Star" Screw-cutting Engine Lathe was operated via foot pedals. Chief among its many
      virtues was its outstanding construction, described as "Heavy, rigid, accurate, correct in design and finish,
      combining
      throughout the best material, with the highest class of workmanship."
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">

    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Catalogs</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1912_Catalog100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Hammacher Schlemmer publishes catalog No. 115, a 300-page edition featuring tools for machinists and metal
      workers. The
      opening page serves notice of the company's tradition for quality and innovation: "Since 1848 we have been selling
      tools
      to the trade. We have always aimed to sell strictly high-grade goods, and to keep in advance of all improvements
      introduced which bore evidence of real practical value."
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- ------------------------SLIDE 5-1918----------------------- -->
<li class="cd-h-timeline__event text-component">
  <div class="cd-h-timeline__event-content container">

    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <div>
        <h2 class="cd-h-timeline__event-title">1918</h2>
        <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Hammacher History</em>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-modal-instruct">
        <p class="timeline-modal-tip">Click on images to enlarge</p>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1918_HS_History100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Despite the fact that there are fewer than 600 automobiles in New York City and no gas stations, Hammacher
      Schlemmer
      introduces the first Auto Parts Department, selling parts and tools for the "horseless carriage" including a
      Motorist
      Touring Kit, which allows drivers to fix a flat or blown gasket.As the automobile gains in popularity and begins
      to come
      into more widespread use, Hammacher Schlemmer purchases their own automobile which they used to begin the first
      home-delivery parcel service for customers-a novel idea in its day.
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">


    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">US History</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1918_US_History100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Theodore Roosevelt becomes the first American President to ride in an automobile when he rides in a Columbia
      Electric
      Victoria through Hartford, Connecticut.
    </p>



    <hr class="timeline-divider">


    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Extraordinary Items</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1918_Extraordinary100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      Weighing up to 750 lbs., the "Star" Screw-cutting Engine Lathe was operated via foot pedals. Chief among its many
      virtues was its outstanding construction, described as "Heavy, rigid, accurate, correct in design and finish,
      combining
      throughout the best material, with the highest class of workmanship."
    </p>

    <hr class="timeline-divider">


    <div class=timeline-image-flex>
      <em class="cd-h-timeline__event-date">Media</em>
      <img class="responsive-timeline-img"
        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1918_Media100x100.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="cd-h-timeline__event-description color-contrast-medium">
      To help motorists reduce their repair bills, Hammacher Schlemmer offers the tourist autokit, "the highest type of
      repairing outfit procurable". The kit contains 38 tools for both permanent and emergency use, "conveniently packed
      in a
      strong, leather-edged canvas roll."
    </p>  
  </div>
</li>
      </ol>
    </div> <!-- .cd-h-timeline__events -->
  </section>



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>





  <!-- Scroll to top button -->
  <footer class="timeline-scrollToTopBtn">
    <button class="scrollToTopBtn">&uarr;</button>
  </footer>
  <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script> <!-- util functions included in the CodyHouse framework -->
  <script src="assets/js/swipe-content.js"></script> <!-- A Vanilla JavaScript plugin to detect touch interactions -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/timeline-scrollToTopBtn.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  
  // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
  var img = $('.myImg');
  var modalImg = $("#img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  $('.myImg').click(function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  var newSrc = this.src;
  modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  });
  
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      }
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you get this similar but different image src?

Comment: The small image is the thumbnail and has its own src. I would like the first modal to be this src https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add the "large" image as an extra attribute to the image like so:

```
<img class="myImg" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History-100x100_1.jpg" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100px;" data-large-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/img.triggermail.io/hammacher/1839_HS_History.jpg">
```

and replace `var newSrc = this.src;` with `var newSrc = this.dataset.largeSrc;` or `var newSrc = this.getAttribute('data-large-src');`

I didn't test this but this should work.

You could read here more about the `dataset` attributes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: That is a great solution, thank you. I was also having difficulty of closing the modal when the user clicks outside the image box (rather than just the "x" icon). Again, I was trying to follow W3 schools tutorial to understand the JS but they seem to not include the JS in the example code.